# Remove park of permalink from WP Job Manager listing

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins

I have a job website which puts jobs on the following URL:

https://www.jarsolutions.co.uk/job/housing-solutions-officer-2/

This is from the plugin WP Job Manager and I'm trying to simply remove the /job/ part, so it looks like this:

https://www.jarsolutions.co.uk/housing-solutions-officer-2/

The trouble being, if I remove it from the permalinks settings and leave if blank, it fills it in with the default /jobs/.

I've found this function that allows me to change it to anything I like, BUT I can't find how to adjust it to get rid of it completely or change it to nothing...

```
function change_job_listing_slug( $args ) {
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = _x( 'careers', 'Job permalink - resave permalinks after changing this', 'job_manager' );
  return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_job_listing', 'change_job_listing_slug' );
```

This bit of code if from their own website here: https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-changing-the-job-slugpermalink/ where it also gives code snippets that add things to the url... but again it doesn't give any info on removing things from he URL.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would really help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From the plugin author's site you referenced I do notice that it says:

> Note: Since WP Job Manager version 1.27.0, the job permalinks can be
> changed inside Settings -> Permalinks, under the Optional section.
>
> For the previous versions of WP Job Manager, please refer to the guide below. Thanks!

Which is where it lists seven different code examples.

In playing with this myself, I can't get any of the code examples to work (they break in weird ways).

So I'm guessing that if you're running a version past 1.27.0 then those code examples no longer work.

I tried playing around with some rewrite rules to remove the /job from the url, but the problem is, everything about the plugin is looking for a keyword (default: job) by which it will search the content.

If it is removed, WordPress will expect that the url must be a Page. It is possible to remove it, but it requires a non-trivial amount of effort.

Best bet is to either submit a support ticket with WP Job Manager and hope they put it on their roadmap, or pay a plugin developer such as myself to write the code necessary to let you do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can remove custom taxonomy slugs («**job**») from term URLs:

Here is the main part of thе code, you can insert it into your current theme **functions.php**, just do not forget to change taxonomy names/slugs in each function to your own values.

```
add_filter('request', 'rudr_change_term_request', 1, 1 );

function rudr_change_term_request($query){

    $tax_name = 'product_cat'; // specify you taxonomy name here, it can be also 'category' or 'post_tag'

    // Request for child terms differs, we should make an additional check
    if( $query['attachment'] ) :
        $include_children = true;
        $name = $query['attachment'];
    else:
        $include_children = false;
        $name = $query['name'];
    endif;


    $term = get_term_by('slug', $name, $tax_name); // get the current term to make sure it exists

    if (isset($name) && $term && !is_wp_error($term)): // check it here

        if( $include_children ) {
            unset($query['attachment']);
            $parent = $term->parent;
            while( $parent ) {
                $parent_term = get_term( $parent, $tax_name);
                $name = $parent_term->slug . '/' . $name;
                $parent = $parent_term->parent;
            }
        } else {
            unset($query['name']);
        }

        switch( $tax_name ):
            case 'category':{
                $query['category_name'] = $name; // for categories
                break;
            }
            case 'post_tag':{
                $query['tag'] = $name; // for post tags
                break;
            }
            default:{
                $query[$tax_name] = $name; // for another taxonomies
                break;
            }
        endswitch;

    endif;

    return $query;

}


add_filter( 'term_link', 'rudr_term_permalink', 10, 3 );

function rudr_term_permalink( $url, $term, $taxonomy ){

    $taxonomy_name = 'product_cat'; // your taxonomy name here
    $taxonomy_slug = 'product_cat'; // the taxonomy slug can be different with the taxonomy name (like 'post_tag' and 'tag' )

    // exit the function if taxonomy slug is not in URL
    if ( strpos($url, $taxonomy_slug) === FALSE || $taxonomy != $taxonomy_name ) return $url;

    $url = str_replace('/' . $taxonomy_slug, '', $url);

    return $url;
}
```

And do not forget about 301 redirect from old URLs, it is required for your website SEO.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'rudr_old_term_redirect');

function rudr_old_term_redirect() {

    $taxonomy_name = 'product_cat';
    $taxonomy_slug = 'product_cat';

    // exit the redirect function if taxonomy slug is not in URL
    if( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $taxonomy_slug ) === FALSE)
        return;

    if( ( is_category() && $taxonomy_name=='category' ) || ( is_tag() && $taxonomy_name=='post_tag' ) || is_tax( $taxonomy_name ) ) :

            wp_redirect( site_url( str_replace($taxonomy_slug, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ), 301 );
        exit();

    endif;

}
```

The code was tested with different hierarchical and non-hierarchical taxonomies and works great with this permalink settings.

Comment: Thanks so much for this Navnish! Apologies for the late reply... the taxonomies are called: job_listing_category - Ive tried to replace product_cat with job_listing_category, but nothing yet - Im sure its not that simple and I'm missing something!! So I need to add slugs for every category I have? Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: @ShaunTaylor Please, do share the code that you have written in functions.php for making that taxonomy. So can guide you on exact words

Comment: Hi :) the job section is actually a plugin here: https://wpjobmanager.com but looking at the plugin files, the custom post type is: job_listing with a taxonomies of: job_listing_type - job_listing_category - it seems....

Comment: The slugs for the job categories are: education - entry-level - environmental-health - executive-search - finance-accounting - graduate - housing - human-resources - office-support - procurement-supply-chain - property-management-construction - supported-housing - technology - Is this what you mean? Thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove 'job/' from URL, you have to follow below steps

Step 1: Change Permalink setting to 'Post name'
Step 2: Create Job as a 'Post'

If you dont want to create in Post, you can't remove 'job/' from URL unless you add 'job-' as a prefix in your URL(https://www.jarsolutions.co.uk/job-housing-solutions-officer-2/)

Answer (score 0):

To Remove job slug or permalink you can use the "Remove CPT" Plugin if you are using WordPress or any service of WP Job Manager. I used it on my website and now you can see the extra base or category base is gone https://mappians.com/hardrockhotelsmaldives here is my [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BelfR.png) of a naked URL that is looking awesome without any base.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).